# docker-composeでup --buildしてもエラーになる

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

docker-composeを利用してjupyter notebookを開こうと思ったら以下のようなエラーが出力されました。
解決方法をご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。

```
Building jupyter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 126, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1070, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1066, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 615, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 346, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 1147, in build
compose.service.BuildError: (<Service: jupyter>, {'message': 'invalid reference format'})

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 78, in main
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str
[9413] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

docker-compose.ymlの中身は以下の通りです。

```
version: "3"
services:
  jupyter:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/tmp/working
    working_dir: /tmp/working
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    command: jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root --LabApp.token=''
```

Answer (score 1):

docker-compose.ymlファイルの中でcontainer_name:を任意の名前で設定したところ実行することができました。